# Can a single property be used in multiple Bean IDs?

Tags: spring

I have a few SQL queries which are exactly the same but used for different bean ids/classes within my beans XML.  Can you create a single property, not tied to a specific bean, and inject it into the bean ids as necessary?

Below is just an example of two exact properties in two different beans.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">


<bean id="regionalPage" class="com.test.RegionalPageDao">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="activeList">
        <value><![CDATA[select * from regionalTable]]></value>
    </property> 
</bean>
<bean id="regionalBackup" class="com.test.RegionalPageBackupDao">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="activeList">
        <value><![CDATA[select * from regionalTable]]></value>
    </property> 
</bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Define all you properties in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and they will be available in your project wherever you want to use them.
do

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties">
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="activeList"><![CDATA[select * from regionalTable]]></prop>
            ...
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And now in you bean definition

```
<bean id="regionalPage" class="com.test.RegionalPageDao">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="activeList">
        <value>${activeList}</value>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

and so on.
Please have a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1298991/3892213)

Comment: Thanks Maneesh.  Exactly what I was looking for.